# C#8.0 switch statements and local variables

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0

Trying to understand the limits of new C#8.0 syntax of the switch statement I'm trying convert some old code from C#7.0 to C#8.0. I would like to use the locally introduced variable (pattern matched), but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

For reference, `propertySelectorExpression` is of type `Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> propertySelectorExpression`

Old code:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
switch (propertySelectorExpression.Body)
{
    case MemberExpression me:
        propertyInfo = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
        break;
    case UnaryExpression ue:
        propertyInfo = (ue.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo;
        break;
}
```

New code (attempt, does not compile):

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
propertyInfo = switch (propertySelectorExpression.Body)
{
    MemberExpression me => me.Member as PropertyInfo,
    UnaryExpression ue => (ue.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo
}
```

or

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
switch (propertySelectorExpression.Body)
{
    MemberExpression me => propertyInfo = me.Member as PropertyInfo,
    UnaryExpression ue => propertyInfo = (ue.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo
}
```

What am I doing wrong or assuming wrong?

Comment: "does not compile", could you post the compiler error and point to the line it complains about?

Comment: Also, `switch (x) { ... }` is not the new syntax, the new syntax is `x switch { ... }`, so try `propertyInfo = propertySelectorExpression.Body switch { ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the syntax of the two uses of `switch`.

You have:

- switch **statement**
- switch **expression**

The syntax for a switch **expression** is `<expression> switch { <patterns> }`, so this should compile:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
propertyInfo = propertySelectorExpression.Body switch // <-- noticed the switched order
{
    MemberExpression me => me.Member as PropertyInfo,
    UnaryExpression ue => (ue.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo
}
```

(though you'll get a warning by the compiler that the switch expression doesn't handle all possible inputs)

The syntax for a switch **statement** (the last example of code in your question) uses `case` instead of the lambda syntax, so this should compile:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
switch (propertySelectorExpression.Body)
{
    case MemberExpression me:
        propertyInfo = me.Member as PropertyInfo;
        break;
    case UnaryExpression ue:
        propertyInfo = (ue.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo;
        break;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the kind help and apologies - I indeed mixed the two uses the syntax.. it now works

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```cs
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;
propertyInfo = propertySelectorExpression.Body switch
{
    MemberExpression me => me.Member as PropertyInfo,
    UnaryExpression ue => (ue.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo
}
```

For further information please see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) about new switch expression format

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet should work, variable comes before the `switch` keyword

```cs
var propertyInfo = propertySelectorExpression.Body switch
{
    MemberExpression me => (me.Member as PropertyInfo),
    UnaryExpression ue => ((ue.Operand as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo),
    _ => null
};
```

You have to manage the default value, which is null on your case. The `default` case is replaced with a `_` discard.